# Valve Extender for Kids Bike

Tags: innertube, valves, children

I can't seem to fit my bike pump onto my son's bike. The tires are too small, and there isn't enough of a gap to put the head of a bike pump on the valve.

Are there any valve extenders (not permanent) that I can use when I need to inflate his bike tires?

Comment: Might not be practical, but I had a similar problem on a pram with plastic wheels and drilled new valve holes at an angle.

Comment: @alex: Clever solution. I will try that out if I can't find an affordable option. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: You'll need to fill the old hole with something too, or it'll pop the tires when you try and pump them up.

Comment: @alex: Thanks. I will try the bendy extension/hose that Batman suggested below. I just need to find them :-)

Comment: I'd probably avoid drilling out a new valve hole. For one, theres the rim integrity you have to worry about along with tube damage and other factors. Not to mention the abundance of pumps and adapters available.

Comment: Yeah, an adapter is the best idea, that's why I didn't add it as an answer. But, wheels that are too small to fit the pump head inside of are not usually under that much stress. I tried this because specialist bits and pieces are hard to get hold of here.

Comment: I have deep-ish rims on my road bike, so use screw-on valve extenders all the time. But the question is, can you obtain presta tubes for your son's bike?

Comment: I don't understand how tire size would effect this.  You can get tubes with longer values.  Did you try pushing in from the tire side with your thumb?

Comment: @Blam 12 inch tires don't leave a lot of room to work with.  To make it worse, the hubs on the wheels tend to be a bit larger as well (oversized front or coaster brake rear).  Straight valves just don't really work well.  I have a hard time with my air compressor chuck and it is as small as you can get.

Comment: @Marwan are we talking 12 inch wheels here?

Comment: I've drilled a lot of holes in a lot of rims, and very rarely had problems.  That being said, it isn't something I'd recommend to someone without a drill press and a good idea of what forces are exerted where on a bicycle rim.  "Bendy" adapters or a pump with a flexible head are a much better answer.

Comment: @BPugh : Yes, they are 12 inch wheels.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Slime makes some [valve extenders for Schrader valves](http://www.slime.com/shop/valve-extenders/)
[image]
, and if you have a Presta valve you can use a Presta to Schrader valve adapter (and if you really want, you can attach a Schrader valve extender to that, since you can buy the Schrader valve extenders at Walmart or whatever)

[image].

Some companies (like [Topeak](http://www.topeak.com/products/Pumps/PrestaValveExtender)) make Presta valve extenders as well:
[image: topeakpresta]

That being said, you can also use a little hose attached to the pump to better access the valve like the ones offered with some Lezyne hand pumps if the chuck is too big.

An example of a bendy extension hose is [image].

There are also 90 degree extenders which you screw on:

[image]

Comment: I don't think these'll work, they're usually not bendy.

Comment: @Batman That looks like a good option. Are they permanent? Easy on, easy off? Do you know, roughly, how much they are?

Comment: @alex: updated with some bendy options

Comment: @Batman: The bendy option looks like exactly what I had in mind. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Marwan: Maybe 2-3 bucks for the ones from the car parts department (schrader valve). If you go to a bike shop and ask them for some, it will probably be 4-5 bucks. At that point, id get the little blue foot pump that everyone had for pumping up soccer balls or something since the chuck is small enough on those (the double sided nature of a lot of track pumps like my Topeak Joe Blow Sport II might be the cause of the problem, so you could possibly just try a different chuck as well).

Comment: @Batman: Thanks so much, your suggestions are great. What do you call those bendy hose extension?

Comment: I'd just google (flexible or bendy) (schrader) valve extender hose (Amazon comes up with http://www.amazon.com/Accu-gage-Chek-Spare-Valve-Extender/dp/B0006O2S8M).

Comment: @Batman: You are a life saver, thanks so much for the detailed answer and comments :-)

Comment: +1 Useful answer, I was unaware that extenders existed for Schrader valves

Comment: This is a useful answer, but if we are talking little kids bike then it is over kill.  I know sunlite has angled valves for 12 inch wheels.  I used them on both metal and plastic wheels.

Comment: @BPugh : Yup, looking for kids bike. The angled valves are a good idea. Didn't know they had them.

Comment: Batman. You are amazingly knowledgeable . Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 7):

You could always buy some new tubes with the valve set at a 45 degree angle. Schwalbe sell them for £5/6 depending on the size you need. Easiest way I'd say and saves you faffing about drilling holes or screwing valve extenders on and off.