# How to attach mini-pump to valve on kids' bike with no space to manoeuver?

Tags: pump, schrader

I bought a new, unused mini-pump from Ebay, here:

https://bit.ly/2HbbYRW

From the enlarged views, you can see that the pump works with both Presta and Schrader valves.

For two kid's bikes, I can only get the pump to fit one valve out of four. For the other three, I seem to be screwing forever, with no mating.

Here's some info.

- I use the Schrader setting. So the valve end of the flexible extension is screwed fully in.
- The pump fits my car (UK)
- All caps fit easily on all bikes.
- A cap from my car fits all valves on both bikes.
- All the caps from the bikes fit my car.
- All caps, including the car are countersunk. So roughly 4 pitches of thread are missing. This makes the cap self-centering, so it's easier to start the thread, even if the attitude is slightly incorrect. I think If the threads on the flexible extension had been countersunk, I might have succeeded.
- The flexible extension is not as flexible as they were 50 years ago. Those extensions could easily form an "S" shape. There's not much space for my fingers (but more space than with a chuck). The reduced flexibility of the current extension means that it's difficult to angle the knurled end such that the axis of the knurling is inline with the axis of the valve. So the angle is offset by about 2 or 3 degrees, which is enough to prevent the threads from mating. I suppose a stronger guy with leather-tipped fingers might be able to do it.

I would be grateful for any advice on how to fit the pump to the valve.

Thanks.

---

Edit:  All the above info about car caps and bike caps was to prove that I have a schrader valve rather than a presta valve.

But I've just seen photos of these two valves here, and there's absolutely no resemblance (as many people probably know):

http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_u-v.html#valve

So, based on these photos, my valves are definitely schrader.

[image: From linked ebay listing]
[image: From linked ebay listing]

Comment: I think this pump may be the sort that screws in place on Presta valves but just pushes down over Schrader to inflate.

Comment: But in my OP I mention that the pump screws on to my car valves, and I managed to screw it on to ONE valve out of four on the bikes. It's definitely a screw fitting. It screws on, and then unscrews off. Can I put a drop of 3-in-1 oil on the valve threads, or WD-40? Or is that a no-no?

Comment: Light 3-in-1 oil would be fine - it could be a sharp thread, and after a little usage might work better.   I've got an identical hose on my topeak mini pumps, and it is a bit of a fag to get on.   Try bringing the hose down onto the valve stem as much as possible, even if you have to thread it between the spokes a bit.

Comment: Silly thought - are you positive its not a woods/dunlop valve?  They would use the presta/french  setting on the pump.

Comment: @Criggie. I reserve the right to silly thoughts on this thread, thanks :-) The second link in my OP shows a Woods valve, which is what we used 50 years ago (although it never had a name, AFAIK). The distinguishing features are the knurled sleeve to contain the tubing, and the threaded anchor ring to prevent the valve from disappearing inside the rim during a flat - which occurred twice a week.

Comment: Removing the first 2-3 threads of the extension might make things easier. The dust caps have the first four threads removed, and they mate easily. Maybe I could try with a reamer or oversized drill. I think the rotation  - and the bit - might need to be counter-clockwise to avoid ripping the new starting point for the thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a stirrup pump on kids bikes - no space for chuck?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/54132/how-to-use-a-stirrup-pump-on-kids-bikes-no-space-for-chuck)

Comment: @RoboKaren, the other post is dead, because there's no space to insert a chuck and then twist the lever until it's co-axial. This current post relates to a mini-pump. There's absolutely no duplication of any fact, opinion, or comment between the posts. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Valve Extender for Kids Bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/25010/valve-extender-for-kids-bike)

Answer (score 1):

Angled valve-pump adapters help in those cases. **[Google them](https://www.google.com/search?q=angled%20valve%20adapters&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab)**, or ask at local bicycle shops.

As an example, something like **[Topeak's "Pressure-Rite" Schrader adaptor](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Topeak%20Pressure-Rite%20Schrader%20Valve%20Adapter)**.

Comment: Best not to just post links to "this", since links often die. In this case, the product name was included in the URL anyway, but I edited to include it in the post.